# How can I determine if a video can be encoded successfully with HEVC (x265) encoding

Tags: command-line, bash, video, hevc

I'm testing out converting some videos to HEVC encoding utilizing ffmpeg and libx265 and I've discovered that the the input width must be divisible by 8 in order to successfully re-encode. I would like to determine whether a re-encode will be successful without attempting the encode and then examining the output. Ideally I'd like to do this in a bash script. My skills are somewhat limited in this regard and much of what I have come up with thus far is far less than elegant.

For example I know that I can do the math with bc as in:

```
 echo 'scale=2;576/8' | bc
72.00
```

and I can obtain the width via

```
width=$(mediainfo $filename | grep "Width" | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')
```

but the former doesn't exactly answer the question is the width divisible by 8 and the latter is ugly and uses too many pipes which research indicates is less then efficient.

I've got the ffmpeg command line for re-encoding sorted to my satisfaction using:

`ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:a copy -c:v libx265 -preset "$preset" -crf 25 "$target"`

and I intend to scale the video to a width divisible by 8 if it isn't already but I'm looking for better solutions than I've come up with thus far for determining if scaling is required and how to determine the closest width divisible by 8 to scale to.

Comment: I'm accepting Andrew.46 answer for putting me on the right track but using my "simpler and faster" approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will correct the *width* to a number divisible by 8 and then correctly *rescale* the *height* to a number divisible by 8 while maintaining correct aspect ratio:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> \
       -c:a copy \
       -c:v libx265 -preset medium -x265-params crf=28 \
       -vf scale="trunc(iw/8)*8:-8" \
       <output>
```

As a bonus if the width is already divisible by 8 there will be no change in the output width and no error from FFmpeg.

An explanation for the scale syntax, remembering that the syntax is `-vf scale=width:height`:

**1. Output Width Calculation:**

- `iw/8`: The width of the input video stream will be divided by 8. So an original width of 690 would create a number 86.25
- `trunc`: The number 86.25 would be 'truncated' to 86
- `*8`: 86 would be multiplied by 8 to give a final width of 688 which of course is divisible by 8!

**2. Output Height Calculation:**

- `-8`: FFmpeg will calculate a height that is divisible by 8 but which also maintains the correct aspect ratio of the original file

In a perfect world hevc encoding is run with encoding units of 8x8, 16x16, 32x32 etc and this syntax guarantees this. More details of this [here...](https://codesequoia.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/hevc-ctu-cu-ctb-cb-pb-and-tb/)

**References:**

- [FFmpeg and H.265 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265)
- [Scaling (resizing) with ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20%28resizing%29%20with%20ffmpeg)
- [FFmpeg: 3. Expression Evaluation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation)
- [HEVC – What are CTU, CU, CTB, CB, PB, and TB?](https://codesequoia.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/hevc-ctu-cu-ctb-cb-pb-and-tb/)

Comment: That's useful, but you are correct, it's not quite what I'm after.  In the test cases I've seen thus far the width is usually only a couple pixels off divisible by 8 and such a small percentage of width I'm not too concerned about the minor change in aspect ratio.

Comment: I think you put me on the right track though.. testing..

Comment: With a little further thought perhaps better syntax for your needs is this: `-vf scale="trunc(iw*a/8)*8:-8"`.  But the maths is wrong as this blows up the output size....

Comment: OK I think I can go one better: `-vf scale="trunc(iw/8)*8:trunc(ih/8)*8"`. This divedies width by 8 and then uses trunc to knock off the decimals and multiples by 8 again to gain the real size. Same for height. Not sure if this would destroy the aspect ration though with really odd screen dimensions...

Comment: The height doesn't need to be divisible by 8 for x265, just the width ;-) see my edited answer.

Comment: -vf scale="trunc(iw/8)*8:-8" rather :)

Comment: The syntax I have altered in my answer gets around the issue of your command `-vf scale=-8:ih` where the input height might not be a number divisible by 8...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37766/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-andrew-46).

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining the width is relatively simple with `mediainfo`. If you don't have it you can install it with `sudo apt-get install mediainfo`

`width=$(mediainfo '--Inform=Video;%Width%' $filename)`

Determining divisibility by 8 can be done via

```
if [ $(( $width % 8 )) -eq 0 ] ; then
   echo "Your number is divisible by 8 – you may convert it”
else
   echo "Video width is not divisible by 8 – it needs scaling to re-encode it."
fi
```

**A far simpler and faster approach inspired by @andrew.46 and a bit more research and testing is to let ffmpeg do the work with**

`ffmpeg -i $inputfilename -c:a copy -c:v libx265 -preset veryfast -x265-params crf=25 -vf scale=-8:ih $outputfilename`

the `-vf scale=-8:ih` setting insures that the width is divisible by 8 (-8) and uses the input height (ih) accordingly to maintain aspect ratio.

Sources: `man mediainfo`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376477/geting-video-information-from-mediainfo

https://superuser.com/questions/49765/how-to-make-a-statement-that-checks-if-something-is-divisible-by-something-else

[How can I determine if a video can be encoded successfully with HEVC (x265) encoding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752014/how-can-i-determine-if-a-video-can-be-encoded-successfully-with-hevc-x265-enco/752043#752043)

http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale

Comment: This is the solution I'm using after further testing but I'm accepting @andrew.46 answer for putting me on the right track